# cannot view google map when using symfony framework

Tags: php, google-maps, symfony

I am developing a website for my school project and I don't know why the the Google map for the direction service doesnot show up. And the console log in firebug doesnot show any error.

here is the my [index.html.twig file](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/429d93ef3e58fb881005)

my css file:

```
#map-canvas{
 height: 500px;
 width: 800px;
 background: blue;
}
```

if i take out the code from symfony i am able to see the map. I don't know what mistake am i doing.

Can someone help me....

Comment: why -1..??  and for What reason..???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Geez it was so simple.. forgot to add initialise function to the body element

```
 <body onload="initialize()">
```